# С кем или с чем?

Tags: орфография

Как-то на глаза попалась старая фотография из рубрики "Нарочно не придумаешь". Речь, конечно, идет о городе Пушкино, но меня вдруг заклинило: а как надо было сказать в данном случае? "Телефонный разговор с Пушкином?"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, можно так, как Вы предложили, но, чтобы избежать двусмысленности, лучше написать: "...с городом Пушкином"

Answer (score 0):

"с г.Пушкино"...так думаю..а про тот, что под Питером - видимо, "с г.Пушкиным"

Comment: Названия городов склоняются!!!

Comment: >Н. Н. Шпанов. Голубеграмма из Усть-Сысольска (1926) Мы шли со скоростью шестидесяти ― семидесяти километров вместо предсказанных жрецами погоды двадцати. **Проплыли над Пушкином**. В стороне осталось Софрино.

Comment: ну, если не оставлять слово "город", то как раз будет немного смешно  - "Проплыли над Пушкином. В стороне осталось Софрино." но если это в Ленобласти, то "Проплыли над Пушкиным. В стороне остался Павловск".

Comment: А че, здорово уели)